# Two ID's in jQuery selector not working

Tags: jquery, html

I think I have misunderstood something when it comes to selecting an element.

I have the following query:

```
$('#my_id_1 #my_id_2').my_function();

<form id="my_id_1">
  <input id="my_id_2" type="text" />
</form>
```

I though that `my_function()` will only trigger when `my_id_2` is "inside" `my_id_1`.

But the function is also triggered on another page where I have `my_id_2` but not `my_id_1`.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here?

**Code update**

```
$('#my_form #country').my_func().autosuggest_country();


(function () {
  // "Namspace" which also kind of works like an interface
  $.fn.my_func = function(opt) {
    this.autosuggest_country = autosuggest.autosuggest_country ;
    return this;
  }


  var autosuggest = {
    autosuggest_country : function(action) {
      $(this).autocomplete({ (...) });
    }
  }
})(jQuery);
```

**Page 1**

```
<form id="my_form" class=""  method="post" onsubmit="return false;">
  <input id="country" type="text" autocomplete="off"  required="required" />
</form>
```

**Page 2**

```
<div id="mainSection" class="mainGrid">

  <div class="selectCountry">
    <select id="country" name="selectlist_country"> (...) </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not just `$('#my_id_2').my_function();`?

Comment: Please post the `my_function()` too.

Comment: Try `$( '#my_id_1' ).find( '#my_id_2' )`and see if the problem still occurs

Comment: @TomPietrosanti: Because he wants 'will only trigger when my_id_2 is "inside" my_id_1'. Having it your way, my_function() would trigger even when my_id_2 is not inside my_id_1. :)

Comment: Will it ever happen that id2 is outside id1 or id1 is missing? If not, then zero reason to not just do what Tom suggested

Comment: Ok, I see.  Thanks for the clarification.  The selector doesn't decide _when_ to execute the function, but instead it runs the function, using the collection from the selector as `this`.

Answer (score 4):

Your current block of code will create a jQuery selection object of everything that matches the selector, `'#my_id_1 #my_id_2'`, and will then apply the jQuery method `my_function()` to that selector. The method will be called whether or not the selection object is empty, since the object still possesses all of the jQuery methods.

There is a method in jQuery for running a block of code once for each element in a selection. It is the `.each()` method. This should work for what you are doing since an ID should only appear once on a page (and hence `'#my_id_1 #my_id_2'` should only correspond to a single DOM element).

To implement this, you would use code as follows, depending on whether `my_function` is a jQuery method or a function.

Regular function:

```
$('#my_id_1 #my_id_2').each(my_function());
```

jQuery method:

```
$('#my_id_1 #my_id_2').each($(this).my_function());
```

This would call `my_function()` once for each element in  $('#my_id_1 #my_id_2'), which should be either zero times or once. Within the scope of `my_function`, `this` will correspond to the element in the selection in both cases.

**EDIT:** Editing because comments aren't working right now.

You should be able to do:

```
$('#my_form #country').each(
    $(this).my_func().autosuggest_country()
)
```

What you want to do is to apply `my_func()` to each element in `$('#my_form #country')` (or do nothing if the selector is empty), so we use a jQuery selector on `this` inside a `.each()`.  `this` is the DOM element, not the jQuery selector for the DOM, so we need to use `$(this)` to gain access to the jQuery methods. You can then use methods on `this` (which is returned by `my_func()`) with your standard method chaining.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PymtB/).

Comment: See my updated code. I'm not sure where I should put the each.

Answer (score 0):

The function `my_function` is always executed. Does it have the following syntax:

```
$.fn.my_function = function(){
    return this.each(function(){

    });
}
```

If you don't use the `this.each` but just execute your code. It will always be executed! The `.each` makes sure it loops through selected elements.

Comment: The `,` does make sure you select 2 elements. which is not the question. The problem is that the function is always executed. Not only if the element exists. Read the question more carefully please. Though, this might not be the answer. But it is a possibility.

Comment: hmm... it might be. I've updated my code. I am returning `this`. But I though the function should not be triggered unless the page had `#id1 #id2`.

Answer (score 0):

**Id** is supposed to be unique on any page ..

`$('#my_id_1 #my_id_2')`  is not required in the first place.

`Just $('#my_id_2').my_function()`  should do.

So if you want to target only the instance on the particular page you are talking about.. Then give the `input a class name instead.`

```
<form id="my_id_1">
  <input class="my_id_2" type="text" />
</form>
```

Now this will fire only on the page you are expecting

`$('#my_id_1 .my_id_2').my_function();`

Or better

```
`$('.my_id_2', '#my_id_1').my_function();`
```

Comment: OP states that the problem is occurring on another page, and so is reusing the JS across pages. Do it is valid to have two situations with the same element ID.

Comment: Even if the OP has used the sam id in 2 different pages, then it is obvious he would find the function triggering , because technically `$('#my_id_1 #my_id_2')` translates to  `$('#my_id_2')` inside the jquery engine, because it is the id we are talking about

Comment: @Sushanth-- and that's what I'm asking. I always though the selectors responded hierarchically. If that's not the case, then this is not the way to trigger this function on this page only.

Comment: @Sushanth - No it does not translate that way -- If you look at the updated post with the specific code, in form one the selector returns an array with a single element. On form 2 it returns an array with zero elements. With a compound selector, the set of elements considered is reduced by each selector.

Comment: @jalynn2 but the function **is** triggered on both pages right? So when the function looks for values in specific elements which does not exist on Page 2, then I get my JS error?

Comment: @Steven Not according to my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ur8sj/ It doesn't find foo because it isn't a child of bar. Your selector as-is should be doing what you expect.

Comment: @Steven - see ckersch's answer for an explanation of why your function is being called.